# while scanning a JSP page during execution which part of the page will be scanned First

Tags: javascript, css, spring, jsp

I'm a fresher started working in Spring frameworks. recent days i started working in Jsp pages for web developing. And i get struck in few basic fundamentals. A professional JSP can contain CSS,JAVASCRIPT,JSTL tags and much more, and there i'm getting hanged in. While executing the jsp page, script will be loaded first or the CSS, or the JSTL tags. If Somebody can make the execution clear i'll be very happy

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing server and client side. At server side the page will be parsed top down. All text which is not included in special tokens will be sent directly to output (to the browser).

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII" pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
  <style>
    table,th,td { border:1px solid black; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Role</th></tr>
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.empList}" var="emp">
      <tr><td><c:out value="${emp.id}"></c:out></td>
      <td><c:out value="${emp.name}"></c:out></td>
      <td><c:out value="${emp.role}"></c:out></td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
<a href="<c:url value="${requestScope.url }"></c:url>">JournalDev</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Strongly summarized:

In this sample, all text between `<%` and `%>` and inside tokens like `<c:...>` is interpreted by the server. All other text goes directly to the browser.

The browser parses the (generated) output (HTML) top down. References to CSS and javascript files produce other http-requests. Embedded `<script>` are executed as they appear. CSS is collected in tables by the browser.